# org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: me.News

Tags: java, xml

OK,the question is different from the questions with the same title,and I have tried many solutions,but I can't solve it.

Entity:

```
package me;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "news_inf")
public class News {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private String content;

    public void setId(Integer id) {
       this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return this.content;
    }
}
```

and the test

```
package me;

import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.*;
import org.hibernate.service.*;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.*;

public class Test3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration().configure();
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new  StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(conf.getProperties())
            .build();
        SessionFactory sf = conf.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        Session sess = sf.openSession();
        Transaction tx = sess.beginTransaction();
        News n = new News();
        n.setTitle("1234");
        n.setContent("1234");
        sess.save(n);
        tx.commit();
        sess.close();
        sf.close();
    }
}
```

the hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="GBK"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url"> <![CDATA[jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8]]></property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">1234</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">5000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">100</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">2</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property><!--①-->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="me.News"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I  don't know why I am wrong?I need help,thanks!

Comment: perhaps also add the xml

Comment: Are you sure your test is making use of the xml?

Comment: yes,the console has shown the message of the name the password